# How can I completely centre the "feature" section of my layout (please see links)?

Tags: css, html, layout, responsive-design

I have created a layout using DIVs/CSS. I have attached an example image and links below which shows how I would like things to be organized. Within the header, there is a logo and a menu which are cumulatively 1000px in width. The feature, content, and footer sections are also to be 1000px in width. However, the actual background images for ALL sections are 100% in width and are repeated horizontally.

Below is an example of what I want to do:

[image: Example layout concept]

What I have actually put together so far (in terms of the design) can be viewed here: http://ohachem.com/2/. This is what I would like to follow. The CSS can be viewed here: http://ohachem.com/2/style.css

What is the best way to accomplish this? As you can see, the text in the "feature" section does not align completely in the centre. I've tried using clear:both, overflow:hidden, and several other methods, with no luck.

Comment: have you looked at bootstrap? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: You question is too broad, can you narrow it down to a specific issue you are having?

Comment: @watson: If you notice the "feature" section, it is not completely aligned in the centre of the page. I would like to have this centred. Once this is fixed, I am looking into making this layout responsive, but I'm not sure where to start with that.

Comment: @cimmanon Question updated as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "misalignment" of the "featured" text is caused by the floating logo.  Because the float hasn't been cleared and extends outside of your header, it is causing that text to flow around it.  Adding `overflow: hidden` to your `#header` element will correct it, but there's other ways to clear floats without adding extra markup.

Alternately, you could just make your logo the same height as the header.  Right now the height property is set to the same value, but the logo has some extra padding, which is causing the overflow.

Comment: This was a simple solution to the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The website you're pointing to uses a liquid layout, here's a bunch of examples: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/ .

One note, on your example, there's no positioning attributes that I can discern, a large part of making a layout responsive is ensuring it looks consistent across all browsers & screens.

Answer (score 0):

I would **Suggest you to use CSS3 Media** Queries rather than Script for the **Responsive/ Adaptive Web page design.**

Please have a look at [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

These **do not process a lot**, hence **Light weight and most modern browsers and Devices support CSS3** hence a **convenient and reliable Option.**